# Broadcast a transaction, issue with Context missing from thread created by BitcoinJ

Tags: bitcoinj, broadcast

In this code i receive an already signed transaction in the form of a byte array and i would like to broadcast it to the Bitcoin network.

```
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    org.bitcoinj.core.Context.propagate(Constants.CONTEXT)
    if (intent != null) {
        when (intent.action) {
            ACTION_BROADCAST_TRANSACTION -> {
                initializeBlockchain(null, 0)
                val transactionByteArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra("TX")
                val tx = Transaction(Constants.NETWORK_PARAMETERS, transactionByteArray)
                tx.getConfidence().setSource(TransactionConfidence.Source.SELF);
                tx.setPurpose(Transaction.Purpose.USER_PAYMENT);
                SpvModuleApplication.getWallet()!!.maybeCommitTx(tx)
                if (peerGroup != null) {
                    val transactionBroadcast: TransactionBroadcast = peerGroup!!.broadcastTransaction(tx)
                    val future : ListenableFuture<Transaction> = transactionBroadcast.future()

                    future.get() 
  ..........
```

Issue is that in my own code i already propagated the context but then internally in BitcoinJ it creates another thread when it has enough peers, and then broadcast the transaction from this thread, which fails as the Context is not propagated there.

Any pointers as to what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks.

> 09-14 15:14:52.867 8281-8330/com.m.s.test E/ExecutionList: RuntimeException while executing runnable org.bitcoinj.core.TransactionBroadcast$EnoughAvailablePeers@838ec24 with executor org.bitcoinj.utils.Threading$2@7b38d
>                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing context at org.bitcoinj.core.Context.get(Context.java:110) 
>   at org.bitcoinj.core.Transaction.getConfidence(Transaction.java:1198)
>   at org.bitcoinj.core.TransactionBroadcast$EnoughAvailablePeers.run(TransactionBroadcast.java:134)
>   at org.bitcoinj.utils.Threading$2.execute(Threading.java:141)
>   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
>   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
>   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
>   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
>   at org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup$14.onPeerConnected(PeerGroup.java:1938)
>   at org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup$11.run(PeerGroup.java:1565)
>   at org.bitcoinj.utils.Threading$UserThread.run(Threading.java:107)